# How can I load a particular snippet according to a previously saved cookie in shopify?

Tags: cookies, variable-assignment, shopify

How can I load a particular snippet according to a previously saved cookie?
I want to do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = readCookie('cop');
    if (!x) {
      createCookie('cop', 1, 10000);
      {% assign cookie = true %}   
    }else{
      {% assign cookie = false %}
    }
</script>

{% if cookie %}
    {% include 'landing' %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'another_landing' %}
{% endif %}
```

but each time, the cookie is assigned the value 'else' (false), even if the condition enter.

I deleted the cookie 'cop', but immediately after the variable is created cookie has assignet value 'false', so never take the value 'true'. I do not understand where the problem is. I can someone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear up your confusion, when Shopify renders a template (including snippets) it is acting on information server-side. Setting a cookie is a client-side action. Therefore you cannot influence Liquid rendering with a cookie. If you want to include a snippet based on a cookie you should render the results of the snippet into DOM (perhaps hidden as a default) and then expose it client-side based on the presence or absence of the cookie.

Comment: I can include a snippet according to the cookie, but every time cookie has the value false, even if at some point it's true.

Comment: Thank you! I use addClass or removeClass (display or hidden), based on cookie with all snipped included